# Pysimplegui - can't append to list from inside event loop

Tags: list, loops, events, append, pysimplegui

this is my second question on stack**overflow**, you guy's aced the last one for me so I'm hoping ye can do the same for this one...

My problem is this.  One of my hobbies is making picture frames and I have written a simple program to automate the calculation in relation to cutting pieces for the frames and so on.  The code works great until I decided to add a list to add the price of each frame in a batch.

Each time you press the 'calc' button the code is supposed to append the price of a frame to a list and then sum it up at the end but instead of appending to the list, each time I press 'calc' the previous value is overwritten and lost.  I've tried the code outside of pysimplegui and it works fine but unfortunately I can't get it to work using the Pysimplegui module.  I'm assuming I have to get the window to update something but I'm afraid I can't work it out.

I'd appreciate any help on this and I have already spent hours messing with it so this is my last resort.

```
from os import name,close
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI import In, WIN_CLOSED
import sys
import datetime



sg.theme('Reddit')

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Ref: ')]+ [sg.Input(size=(30,1),k="--name--",text_color='Blue')]+[sg.Text('#')]+[sg.Spin([1,2,'3+'],initial_value=1,size=(2,1),k="--spin--",background_color='navajo white')],
    [sg.Text('Print Width')]+[sg.In(size=(5,1),k="--pw--")]+ [sg.Text('Print Length')]+[sg.In(size=(5,1),k="--pl--")]+[sg.Image('toc.png',pad=(80,0))],
    [sg.Text('Stock')]+[sg.In(size=(3,1),k="--stock--",background_color='khaki1')]+[sg.Text('Rabbet')]+[sg.In(size=(3,1),k="--rabbet--",background_color='khaki1')]
    +[sg.Text('Matt')]+[sg.In(size=(3,1),k="--matt--",background_color='khaki1')]+[sg.Text('Overlap')]+[sg.In(size=(3,1),k="--olap--",background_color='khaki1')],
    [sg.ML(size=(40,22),k='--main--')]+[sg.Image('framing.png')],
    [sg.Button('Calculate',k="--calc--",bind_return_key=True,enable_events=True)]+[sg.Save(k="--save--")]+[sg.CloseButton('Close',k='--close--',pad=(140,0))]
    ]

window = sg.Window('Frame Size Calculator',layout,finalize=True)
while True:    
    event, values = window.read()
    #print(f'event = {event}, values = {values}')

    try:
        if event == WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        if event == '--Close--':
            window['--main--'].print('Exit....')
            break
        if values['--spin--']==1:
            discount = 0
        elif values['--spin--']==2:
            discount = .10
        elif values['--spin--']=='3+':
            discount = .20
    
        printSize_w = int(values['--pw--'])
        printSize_l= int(values['--pl--'])
        stock= int(values['--stock--'])
        rabbet= int(values['--rabbet--'])
        matt = int(values['--matt--'])
        olap = int(values['--olap--'])
        frameWidth = stock-rabbet
        mattSize_w = printSize_w+(matt*2)-(olap*2)
        mattSize_l = printSize_l+(matt*2)-(olap*2)
        total_width = mattSize_w+(frameWidth*2)
        total_length = mattSize_l+(frameWidth*2)
        frame_perimeter = (total_length*2)+(total_width*2)
        
        price = float((frame_perimeter*1.5)/100).__round__(2) 
        d_price = float(price-(price*discount)).__round__(2)

        name = str(values['--name--'])
        time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        total_price = []
        
        # *****here's the offending bit of code****
        if event == '--calc--':
            total_price.append(d_price)
            
            window['--main--'].print('- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ','\n',name,'\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ', '\nStock:',stock,' Rabbet:',rabbet,'Matt:',matt,'Overlap:',olap,'mm',
            '\nPrint size =',printSize_l,' x ',printSize_w,'mm',
            '\nMatt Size =',mattSize_l,' x ',mattSize_w,'mm',
            '\nTotal Size (L x W)',total_length,' x ',total_width,'mm',
            '\nFrame Perimeter = ',frame_perimeter,'mm',
            '\nSuggested Price : \u20ac',d_price,
            '\nTotal Price : \u20ac',sum(total_price),
            '\n---------------------------------------------------------------')
            

        if event == '--save--':
            sys.stdout = open("frameSizeLog.txt", "a")
            print(values['--main--'])
            print(time_stamp.strftime('%A %b %d %Y - %H:%M.%S'))
            print('_________________________________________')
            sys.stdout=close(fd=0)
            window['--main--'].print('--saved to file--')
    
    except ValueError:
        window['--main--'].print('Numbers only please')
window.close()
```

Comment: In your event loop, `total_price = []` will clear content of `total_price` when every event generated. Move that statement before your event loop.

Comment: Thanks for that Jason, it's so obvious now when I look at it...!